# Why are emoticons from other device not supported?

Tags: sql, xampp

I'm developing a chat app on Android, using this emoticons library from: https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

and this is the second libary I use with almost the same problem,I tried all I know, searched but the problem is still there.

EmoticonEditText render sent emoticons correctly, but not the received messages.

Like this:

[image]

**The instant messaging works like this:**

**Device A:**

- User sends emoticon
- listview of EmoticonEditTexts is updated
- message stored at local storage (SQLite)
- messages sent to server.

**Device B:**

- messages received from server
- message stored at local storage (SQLite)
- listview of EmoticonEditTexts is updated

**NOTES**

1- **Eeach device can render it's own sent emoticons messages correctly but not emoticons messages       from other devices.**

2-**My messages table in the db has UTF-8_general_ci collation but the messages apear as things like ğğğğğ¤ğ**

3- **this is the param for the http request to send the message:**

```
    String params = "username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") + 
            "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") + 
            "&to=" + URLEncoder.encode(tousername,"UTF-8") +
            "&message="+ URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8") +
            "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("sendMessage","UTF-8")+
            "&";
```

4- **emoticons are named like this emoji_00a9.png**

**What is causing the problem?**

**How to solve it (with clear and simple steps)?**

Comment: THat means you aren't storing non-BMP characters correctly.

Comment: @SLaks any suggestions? I think they're stored correctly on SQLite but not in server, this is why i need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the field/table uses the `utf8mb4` charset. This will allow it to store characters outside the BMP properly.

Comment: @Igancio
I used: ALTER TABLE messages CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 

i tried it for all tables,fields; one by one.Also for the whole db.

it says that the query worked, but when i open the db structure this change is not applied to all tables, neither all fields.
is this related to the problem?

Comment: Did you repopulate the table? Existing data will still be broken.

Comment: thank you for helping me. yes I did this, many times, also tried utf8mb4_general_ci; now the whole db is utf8mb4_general_ci and those weird ğğğğğ¤ğ are gone, but empty boxes charachters took their place. that's a good sign, any other suggestions?